# 身にまとう related question

Tags: translation, meaning

I didn't find 身にまとう in Japanese-English dictionary, but I understood from a Japanese dictionary that it can mean "wear" or "acquire knowledge" I'm wondering if this part means what I think it means:

なにしろ‥‥あらゆるナゾを
身にまとっていますからな。

I'd read it as talking about learning about all the mysteries... Am I very far off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been speaking Japanese since birth, but I doubt that I have seen or heard the expression 「[身]{み}に**まとう**」 used to mean "***to acquire knowledge***".  It might be figuratively used that way by a very small number of people, but it would not be common at all.

Are you sure you are not talking about 「身に**つける**」 instead?

> 「なにしろ・・・あらゆるナゾを 身にまとっていますからな。」

would mean:

> "At any rate, (someone) is such an inscrutable figure."

Or, more literally,

> "At any rate, (someone) is wrapped in all kinds of mysteries."

Comment: Thank you! I saw 身につける as a synonym to 身にまとう at one online dictionary - I guess that was wrong then Thank you very much!

Comment: To clarify, 「身につける」 is often used to refer to learning and acquiring skills and knowledge, but it can also mean "to wear (clothes and accessaries)".  「身にまとう」 is mostly used to refer to wearing (clothes).  In your sentence's case, it is talking about "wearing mysteries" like clothes.